# Unable to locate package packagekit-gtk3-module:i386 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I am trying to install an application which requires this package and when I try to install this package, I am getting the above-mentioned error.

I already updated the apt package list using apt update. What can I do?

I need to install it which is a 32-bit package on a 64-bit ubuntu.

## Edit 1

Adding architecture did not solve the problem:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [438 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [175 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [97.2 kB]
Fetched 1,034 kB in 1s (1,415 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages', as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages', as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'

 sudo apt install packagekit-gtk3-module:i386
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package packagekit-gtk3-module:i386
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the following lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
```

Because the package belong to `universe` repository , package updates are applied through the security updates and `bionic-update`: [packagekit-gtk3-module](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/packagekit-gtk3-module)

A sample source.list (more complete):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install packagekit-gtk3-module:i386
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. Please clarify why in the sample source list, the one line that you said should be on the list, is not there.